# How can I get parameters in express in second callback, because this works only in first?

Tags: javascript, node.js

why when I used `req.isAuthenticated()` in first callback as in `app.get("/"..)` works but if I want use it in second callback as in `app.get("/rezerwacja"..)` it doesn't work and i have the  error:

`TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function`

I need this parameter also in second callback as in ("/rezerwacja"). How can i get it there?

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index.ejs',{isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()})
})

app.get('/rezerwacja', checkAuthenticate,(req,res)=>{
    res.render('reservation.ejs',{isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()})
})


function checkAuthenticate(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.isAuthenticated = true;
        return next()
    }else{
        res.redirect('/logowanie')
    }
}
```

Comment: i read your code and maybe the error because of req doesn't have function isAuthenticated(). Do you can access root endpoint / ???

Comment: try to debug `console.log(req.isAuthenticated())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call next() in `checkAuthenticate`

```js
app.get(
  '/rezervacja', 
  function checkAuthenticate(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      req.isAuthenticated = true; // you are overwriting the req object
      next();
    } else {
      res.redirect('/logonwanie');
    }
  }, 
  (req, res) => { 
    // req.isAuthenticated: true is no longer a function
    // you can console.log(req.isAuthenticated) to check
    res.render('reservation.ejs', { isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated }) 
  }
)
```

Comment: I have it i edited my topic with this code, i tried return next() and next() doesn't help

Comment: @MichałTopór I saw your edits and I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code for `checkAuthenticate` middleware in your question. I think that's re-factoring the `req` object, thus removing the `isAuthenticated` method.

UPDATE: You're assigning `true` to `req.isAuthenticated` in the middleware. This means that, the value of `req.isAuthenticated` can either be a boolean (`not a function`) or a function in the routes. Therefore, before calling the `req.isAuthenticated` function, you should check if it's a function in the first place:

```js
{ isAuthenticated: typeof req.isAuthenticated === "boolean" ? req.isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated() }
```

Comment: But i Have redirecting in this method. How can i do it there:

function checkAuthenticate(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.isAuthenticated = true;
        return next()
    }else{
        res.redirect('/logowanie')
    }
}